# Combine elements from list of lists based on name

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python, so I may have the name of this wrong. The issue I am having is, I have a list as follow

```
lst1 = [{'A': ['99']}, {'B': ['83']}, {'D': ['65']}, {'J': ['90']}, {'A': ['99']}, {'B': ['85']}, {'D': ['63']}, {'J': ['89']}, {'A': ['95']}, {'B': ['79']}, {'D': ['63']}, {'J': ['73']}, {'A': ['98']}, {'B': ['82']}, {'D': ['81']}, {'J': ['91']}]
```

I am trying to see if there is a way to combine the the element within the [] that have the same key, so the resulting list will be

```
new_lst = [{'A': [99, 99, 95, 98]}, {'B': [83, 85, 79, 82]}, {'D': [65, 63, 63, 81]}, {'J': [90, 89, 73, 91]}]
```

I have been banging my head against the monitor for a few days now and I cannot figure it out, I would definitely appreciate any help.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the output format has to be a list of dictionaries like the input, this is very complicated. It gets easy if you use a dictionary directly for the output. You then can use [`dict.setdefault(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```py
inputlist = [
    {'A': ['99']},
    {'B': ['83']},
    {'D': ['65']},
    {'J': ['90']},
    {'A': ['99']},
    {'B': ['85']},
    {'D': ['63']},
    {'J': ['89']},
    {'A': ['95']},
    {'B': ['79']},
    {'D': ['63']},
    {'J': ['73']},
    {'A': ['98']},
    {'B': ['82']},
    {'D': ['81']},
    {'J': ['91']}
]

output = dict()

for dct in inputlist:
    key = list(dct.keys())[0] # get the letter (A, B, D, J)
    output.setdefault(key, []) # create the key in the output dictionary and assign a list to it, if it doesn't exist already
    output[key] += dct[key] # append the number

print(output)
```

Output:

```py
{'A': ['99', '99', '95', '98'], 'B': ['83', '85', '79', '82'], 'D': ['65', '63', '63', '81'], 'J': ['90', '89', '73', '91']}
```

Comment: wow, thx that definitely worked. I appreciate the help